# Confusion Abounds with FactoryGirl: has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am having a hard time figuring out what this error means exactly:

```
    An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
    Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

    FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
      The following factories are invalid:

      * question - Validation failed: Option must 
      exist, Question must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

These are the factories:

```
    # question has many options through quiz
    FactoryGirl.define do
     factory :question, class: 'Question' do
       option "What color are your eyes"
     end
   end 

    # option has many questions through quiz
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :option, class: 'Option' do
        option "blue"
      end
    end

    # JoinTable 
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :quiz, class: 'Quiz' do
        option nil
        question nil
      end
    end
```

My guess is that the `nil` right next to the associations in Quiz factory has something to do with the error. I tried to read through FactoryGirl docs to see how to create the right associations but I do not understand certain things. For example:

- am I supposed to create the associations in the factory for the join table (Question) only?
- more importantly, since I want to first create a question and then tell the question what options it has, how do I achieve this in the Factory?

Thank you!

Edit:

## Option Model:

```
    class Option < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :quizzes
      has_many :questions, through: :quizzes
    end
```

## Question Model

```
   class Question < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :quizzes
     has_many :options, through: :quizzes
   end
```

## Quiz Model

```
    class Some::QuizQuestion < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :questions
      belongs_to :options
    end
```

Comment: I think you need to include your models so we can see the validations in order to get a good answer to this one.

Comment: For your second question, you could use traits to create questions with different options, see: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post the solution to this question.

Main issue/question was:

- why was the validation for the join table failing/returning error below:

  ```
   * question - Validation failed: Option must 
     exist, Question must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
  ```

As I suspected, it was because of the  `nil` value next to both of the associations in QuizQuestion factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quiz, class: 'Question' do
    option nil
    question nil
  end
end
```

Solution was to get rid of the `nil` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `class_name` option to your relationships, I am pretty sure Rails doesn't deal with the `Some` namespace the way you're expecting it to.
For example:

`class Some::QuizQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :some_questions, class_name: 'Some::Question'
  belongs_to :some_questions, through: :some_quiz_questions
end`

Also, that second `belongs_to` doesn't make sense afaict, you are redefining `some_questions` right after defining it.

Comment: That is a typo.  Will correct it now and see what happens.

Comment: The real answer was about the `class_name` option. Did that help with your issue?